# Выполнение корутины в фоновом режиме

Tags: python, asyncio

Как сделать так, чтобы корутина выполнялась в фоне, и не задерживала код?

```py
import socket
import asyncio


async def test():
    print("hi")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("bye")


async def main():
    with socket.create_server(("localhost", 6666)) as server:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        while True:
            client, _ = await loop.sock_accept(server)
            mess = await loop.sock_recv(client, 1024)
            print(mess.decode())
            client.close()
            
            asyncio.create_task(test())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Есть вот такой небольшой тестовый скрипт, тут две функции... Использую `socket`.

Я хочу чтобы `asyncio.create_task(test())` выполнилась и не задерживала код. То есть сделала как бы "новый поток" в стиле asyncio и там эта задача выполнилась. Только как это сделать - не знаю...

Answer (score 1):

ну и по классике жизни, сам написал - сам ответил....

```py
import socket
import asyncio


async def test():
    print("hi")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("bye")


async def main():
    with socket.create_server(("localhost", 6666)) as server:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        server.setblocking(False)

        while True:
            client, _ = await loop.sock_accept(server)
            mess = await loop.sock_recv(client, 1024)
            print(mess.decode())
            client.close()

            asyncio.create_task(test())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

все дело в `server.setblocking(False)` и тогда будет работать как надо (по крайней мере как я хочу)

Comment: а почему не испозуешь https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_server asyncio.loop.create_server  ?

Comment: @eri не удобно использовать...

Comment: зато можно отрабатывать одновременно несколько подключений в оличие от этого